Yarn4+Prisma in typescript project cause TS error despite checkJs being false
I use yarn 4 and prisma.
Prisma is an ORM, this orm has a command prisma generate client, and it generate a package in node_modules/@prisma/client.
Unfortunately with yarn 4, this features does not work as there is no node_modules, and yarn 4 is a requirement for my project.
Prisma as an option to change the output dir of the generated client, which I configured into my workspace, despite ignore those file into git.
It work fine, but now I am struggling with the Typescript option allowJs:true combinated with checkJs: false.
Bunch of error are now script except TS9005 and TS9006
I can't use annotation to ignore those two files as the client are often re-generated.
How can I ignore those two errors without using noEmitOnError that will disable error on all my project, without downgrading yarn, and without removing prisma ?
